# How to get closest double values from ArrayList in Android

Tags: java, android

I've a list of double values named valuelist. I have a edittext and a button . when I press the button it will show the closest double value of edittext from valuelist.how to do that ?btw I'm new to app development and dont know any method to use :(

And my codes are:-

```
List<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();
    list.add(1.38);
    list.add(2.56);
    list.add(4.3);

EditText input = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etinput);
Button convert = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btconvert);
TextView result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvresult);

double ivalue = String.valueOf(result.getText());
```

so if ivalue is 2.5 then when I press the button it will set result to 2.56 as it is the nearest double value of array list. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the list and get the difference between the `EditText` value and the current list item, and the lowest difference value will lead to the nearest item to the `EditText` value.

```
List<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();
list.add(1.38);
list.add(2.56);
list.add(4.3);

EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etinput);
Button convert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btconvert);
TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvresult);


convert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        double ivalue = Double.parseDouble(input.getText().toString());
        double difference = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        double nearstItem = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        for (double item : list) {
            if (difference > Math.abs(ivalue - item)) {
                difference = Math.abs(ivalue - item);
                nearstItem = item;
            }
        }

        result.setText(String.valueOf(nearstItem));

    }
});
```

Make sure to handle the non-double input values to the `EditText`